# How would I put these recurrence relation terms into a summation?

Tags: summation, recurrence-relations

I was given these terms as part of a recurrence relation and I need to put it into a summation in order to solve it. $T(n)=2^{k}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{k}}\right) + 2^{k-1}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{k-1}}\right) + ... +\dfrac{n^{2}}{4}+8+\dfrac{n^2}{2}+4+n^2+2+2n^{2}+1$

The term $2^{k}T\left(\dfrac{n}{2^{k}}\right)$ is $0$ based on the assumption that $k=\log_{2}n$ and that $T(1)=0$.

I have tried putting these terms in a summation and this is what I have so far

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{n^2}{2^{i-1}}+2^{i}$

I am not sure if this is the correct expression because I cannot get this into an expression with a known formula. I know the geometric sum formula but simplifying the first term in the summation will give a negative exponent and I don't think that works with the geometric sum.

The answer that was given in the problem was $T(n)=4n^{2}-3n-1$. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong?

***edit**

Here is what I have tried so far

$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{n^{2}}{2^{i-1}}+2^{i} =n^{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{2^{i-1}}+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}$

I then simplified $\dfrac{1}{2^{i-1}}$ to $\dfrac{2}{2^{i}}$ and now I have

$2n^{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{2^{i}}+\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}$

I know there is a formula for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{i}$ but I am having trouble with $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{1}{2^{i}}$, I can use the exponent trick to turn $\dfrac{1}{2^{i}}$ into $2^{-i}$ but I do not know of any formula that works for $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1}2^{-i}$. That is the part I am stuck on.

Comment: A negative exponent on $2$ is a positive exponent on $1/2$.

Comment: Yes, I know that trick but it didn't help me in this case. I'm not sure if I set up the summation correctly. It seems to make sense but I have no idea how to sum it up because it isn't in a form with a known formula.

Comment: But but but ... you say the first term gives you a negative exponent, and you say you know how to turn a negative exponent into a positive one. Once you've done that, there isn't any negative exponent any more. It was the negative exponent that was giving you trouble, so, once it's gone, what trouble could you be having? Why not edit into the question what you tried to do --- then maybe someone will be able to help you over the rough patch.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have edited the question with what I have tried and what I am getting stuck on.

Comment: OK. Now, $2^{-i}$ is the same thing as $(1/2)^i$. No negative exponent any more, right? So, if you know what to do with $\sum2^i$, don't you also know what to do with $\sum(1/2)^i$? If not, maybe you need to indicate what you know how to do with $\sum2^i$ --- what formula you use, and where that formula comes from. Then we can show you how the same ideas handle $\sum(1/2)^i$.

Comment: I'm a little confused on how you got $(1/2)^{i}$ from $2^{-i}$. I thought this was only true if the numerator was also raised to the same power?

Comment: $(1/2)^i=1^i/2^i=1/2^i=2^{-i}$.

Comment: Oh I see... this would only work if the numerator was $1$ because $1$ raised to any power is $1$. If the numerator wasn't a $1$, I wouldn't be able to do this trick right?

Comment: Any time you have $a^i/b^i$, you have $(a/b)^i$. But maybe I miss your point. In any event, if you have a formula for the sum of a geometric progression, that formula involves a symbol $r$, which stands for the common ratio between successive temrs in the sum. You can use that formula whether $r$ is $2$, or $2^{-1}$, or $17/42$, or any other number whatsoever (except, maybe, $r=1$).

Comment: So, are we OK now?